# Valgrind throws no error but not all heap allocations have been freed

Tags: c++, memory-management, valgrind

This is what i get after executing my program with *Valgrind*:

```
1    jscherman@jscherman:~/ClionProjects/algo2-t4-tries$ g++ Set.hpp tests.cpp DiccString.hpp && valgrind --leak-check=yes --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out                      
2    ==6823== Memcheck, a memory error detector
3    ==6823== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
4    ==6823== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
5    ==6823== Command: ./a.out
6    ==6823== 
7    test_empty_dicc...ok
8    test_copy_constructor...ok
9    test_define_defined...ok
10    test_get..ok
11    test_remove...ok
12    test_remove_tiny...ok
13    test_keys...ok
14    ==6823== 
15    ==6823== HEAP SUMMARY:
16    ==6823==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
17    ==6823==   total heap usage: 282 allocs, 281 frees, 275,300 bytes allocated
18    ==6823== 
19    ==6823== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
20    ==6823==    at 0x4C2DC10: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
21    ==6823==    by 0x4EC3EFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
22    ==6823==    by 0x40104E9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
23    ==6823==    by 0x40105FA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
24    ==6823==    by 0x40105FA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
25    ==6823==    by 0x4000CF9: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
26    ==6823== 
27    ==6823== LEAK SUMMARY:
28    ==6823==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
29    ==6823==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
30    ==6823==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
31    ==6823==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
32    ==6823==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
33    ==6823== 
34    ==6823== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
35    ==6823== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It seems like there are no leaks as last line of the output says. Yet, we have also this line:

```
17    ==6823==   total heap usage: 282 allocs, 281 frees, 275,300 bytes allocated
```

How is that i don't have any errors but there is still an allocation that hasn't been freed? Is there something wrong with my program or maybe something being done by *Valgrind* behind the scenes?

Comment: *I'm not going to put here my code because there are no leaks* -- Famous last words.  Why are you so sure your program has no memory leaks?

Comment: That looks like a static initial leak. I assume you don't own the `dl-init.c` code, right ? Its probably just startup code for the runtime library. Props for using valgrind, btw.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm not... my point was that Valgrind says there aren't (as i understand). So, based on the premise that if i had a leak then it would be thrown as an error (right?), i just avoided to put a bunch of code here that i considered unnecessary for the question itself.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm a kind of noob in c++, so i don't know what that is. Can i assume that i am not using it so? :P

Comment: @jscherman Sam's answer gives a nice description of what one-time dynamic C++ runtime startup allocations may be involved, and how they're often suppressed to track down the leaks you *really* care about (i.e. your code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backtrace reported by valgrind shows that the memory allocation in question was made in the initialization function of one of the shared libraries loaded by the application, apparently the C++ library itself.

It is quite common for shared libraries to make one-time allocations for various bits and pieces of data, but not bother to explicitly deallocate them, when they get unloaded.

This does not comprise a memory leak in your own code.

valgrind comes with a list of known allocations of this nature, it's called a "suppression list", for the explicit purpose of suppressing reports about these known one-off allocations.

But, occasionally, these suppression lists do miss an allocation, or two.